# Finding records in a range, rounding down when needed

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a bit difficult to describe, and I'm not sure if this can be done in SQL.  Using the following example data set:

```
ID     Count   Date       
1       0      1/1/2015    
2       3      1/5/2015
3       4      1/6/2015
4       3      1/9/2015
5       9      1/15/2015
```

I want to return records where the Date column falls into a range.  But, if the "from" date doesn't exist in the table, I want to use the most recent date as my "From" select.  For example, if my date range is between 1/5 and 1/9, I would expect to have records 2,3, and 4 returned.  But, if I have a date range of 1/3 - 1/6 I want to return records 1,2,and 3.  I want to include record 1 because, as 1/3 does not exist, I want the value of the Count that is rounded down.

Any thoughts on how this can be done?  I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to replace the `from` date with the latest date before or on that date.  Let me assume that the variables are `@v_from` and `@v_to`.

```
select e.*
from example e
where e.date >= (select max(e2.date) from example e2 where e2.date <= @v_from) and
      e.date <= @v_to;
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT AFTER EDIT:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE BETWEEN (
    SELECT Date
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE Date <= @Start
    ORDER BY Date DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
AND @End
```

Or

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE BETWEEN (
    SELECT MAX(Date)
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE Date <= @Start
)
AND @End
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support analytical functions or the `top` syntax

Comment: Ahh yes I forgot.  They do have Limit though.  I'll update my answer